# Toolbar with segmented controls on pickerview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making an app and I need configure a pickerview with segmented controls in a toolbar how I showing in the image below(app seek jobs), to change values in components each time the user pressing a segmented control, but I don't know how add the segmented control to pickerview's toolbar .

[image]

Comment: When you changes the segment control index you have to reload `pickerview` with new data which you want.

Comment: Ok, but do you know how add segmented control on pickerview's toolbar?

Comment: I think you have done this as I can see in picture

Comment: No, I did not , this picture is the an app named seek jobs , I don't know how add the segmented control to pickerview's toolbar.

Comment: OK, right now I am not on my Mac. So I will post answer tomorrow. And do you want that programmatically or in storyboard?

Comment: I think that programmatically